# How to test if STDIN has something to read (Perl on Windows)

Tags: windows, perl, asynchronous, filehandler

I have encountered a problem in Perl. To test if the `STDIN` file handler has something to read immediately, I would like to program like this.

```
while(1)
{
     my ($l);
     if (TestCanRead(STDIN))
     {
         $l = <STDIN>;
         HandleRead($l);
     }
     else
     {
         HandleNotRead();
     }
}
```

or

```
 while(1)
 {
     my ($l);
     $l = ReadImmediate(STDIN);
     if (defined($l))
     {
         HandleRead($l);
     }
     else
     {
          HandleNotRead();
     }

 }
```

Can somebody tell me how to write the function **ReadImmediate** or **TestCanRead**
on a Windows system? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't have a Windows environment to test on, but Perl makes claims of portability.  So lets assume the Unix solution works.

You want `select` or a wrapper around it.  I usually use `IO::Select`, which looks like this:

```
use IO::File;
use IO::Select;

my $select = IO::Select->new( \*STDIN );

while (1) {
    if (my @ready_FHs = $select->can_read(0)) {
        foreach my $FH (@ready_FHs) {
            say $FH->getline();
        }
    } else {
        say "Nothing to do; napping";
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```